# When converting a string to an int, how do I check if there will be overflow?

Tags: python, casting, overflow

I am trying to convert a string to a 32-bit int and I want to clamp numbers smaller than -2^31 to -2^31 and numbers bigger than 2^31-1 to 2^31-1.

This is my code so far, but for some reason it is not working.

```
import sys

if num > sys.maxsize:
   return 2147483647
elif num < -sys.maxsize - 1: 
   return -2147483648
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You forgot the string to int conversion code

Comment: Use >0x7fffffff or < -0x80000000 instead for signed 32-bit.  sys.maxsize is os-dependent.

Comment: Saying "it is not working" does not tell us anything about **the actual problem**.  Instead, please show what the code actually does, and tell us what you expected  it to do instead.

Comment: `num = max(min(num, sys.maxsize), sys.minsize)`

Comment: `sys.maxsize` will return different numbers on `64 bit` computers. You assumed is a `32 bit`  computer.

Answer (score 0):

If your constraints are specifically 32-bit then you should not be referring to sys.maxsize because that will not give you the correct value in a 64-bit environment.

Much easier to use well-known constants.

Therefore:

```
HI = 2147483647
LO = -2147483648

def convert(s):
    if (i := int(s)) > HI:
        return HI
    return LO if i < LO else i
```